# Gluon build problem - specifies unknown module javafx.graphics

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluonfx

My project was building fine then I wanted to bring dockable window and did https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/DockFX and used it in https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/swaggerific I could not find what made this but my github actions started failing with error below in [linux](https://gist.github.com/ozkanpakdil/1d305c3d530f962f91415f0eb726094f) and [windows](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/swaggerific/actions/runs/8318588274/job/22760740784)

```bash
[Sun Mar 17 22:08:25 UTC 2024][INFO] [SUB] Error: Resource pattern "javafx.graphics:\Qcom/sun/prism/es2/glsl/FillRoundRect_Color.frag\E"s specifies unknown module javafx.graphics
[Sun Mar 17 22:08:25 UTC 2024][INFO] [SUB] com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Resource pattern "javafx.graphics:\Qcom/sun/prism/es2/glsl/FillRoundRect_Color.frag\E"s specifies unknown module javafx.graphics
[Sun Mar 17 22:08:25 UTC 2024][INFO] [SUB]  at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:72)
[Sun Mar 17 22:08:25 UTC 2024][INFO] [SUB]  at com.oracle.svm.hosted.ResourcesFeature.makeResourcePattern(ResourcesFeature.java:288)
[Sun Mar 17 22:08:25 UTC 2024][INFO] [SUB]  at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
```

strange thing the build is working in my linux laptop , but having same error in my windows laptop.

One important thing I changed in swaggerific was I deleted [module-info.java](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/swaggerific/blob/74cd57275e12a9ab59e5b29c3bc99d492bf92822/src/main/java/module-info.java), because in linux I was having classpath and module problems, after I delete module-info all started working. I tried to put that back in but could not solve so far, any input highly appreciated.

Edit 1: Regular graalvm jdk is compiling the package without problem for linux and windows https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/swaggerific/issues/12